# Stop ZSH from trying to correct command

Tags: zsh, line-editor

```
$ knife cookbook download recipe
zsh: correct 'cookbook' to 'cookbooks' [nyae]?
```

How can I get zsh to stop trying to correct cookbook to cookbooks??

cookbooks is a directory where I run the command so I understand why it's doing it, but cookbook is a valid part of the command line.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to disable corrections completely, you should define an alias:

```
alias knife='nocorrect knife'
```

Answer (score 14):

You can add `setopt nocorrectall; setopt correct` to your `~/.zshrc` file to disable this behavior. It will still function for commands, but not for arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to include a list of filenames or patterns to ignore in the `CORRECT_IGNORE_FILE` variable defined in your .zshrc file. In your case, add `CORRECT_IGNORE_FILE="cookbooks"` to your .zshrc file.